# Jenkins concurrent jobs based on a parameter

Tags: jenkins

Is there any way to make parameterized build be concurrent respecting a parameter value.

For example:

Suppose we have a job "Job 1", which have a parameter "Thing", which can be "a", "b" or "c".

If the user build Job 1 with Thing being a, then b, then c, they can run in parallel.

In summary, I want the queue to be based on the parameter instead of the job name.

Is such thing possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no, there is not a way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically change whether job can or can not run in parallel you can use:

```
build.getProject().setConcurrentBuild(true/false)
```

in Execute System Groovy Script.
You can try something like:

```
if(build.properties.environment["Thing"].equals("a")){
    build.getProject().setConcurrentBuild(true)
}
else{
    build.getProject().setConcurrentBuild(false)
}
```

Comment: is not that what I want. I want to make the queue based on a property, not be or not concurrent based on a property value...